# how to make an array of homogeneous data value in array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I want to create a 3x3 array filled with tens.

I know for array filled with zeros or ones, i can use np.zeros() and np.ones(), respectively.

But what about an array filled with tens?

Are there no special ways to do this?

Comment: multiply the `ones` by 10.  or add 10 to the `zeros`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.fill()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) to fill an array with any value.